# How to don't evaluate both functions in list choice if/else alternative?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm in the situation where :

1. The functions contents are created dynamically in string before being evaluated,
2. I don't want to use `if test: dosomething else: dosomethingElse` to compose the content because users can change part of the string content, and I don't want them to have to manage spaces between math expression in conditionnal statement.

So, I use the following list tip: `[dosomethingElse, dosomething][ test ]`, (True/False answser to the test gives me dosomething/dosomethingElse).

The solution works correctly but dosomething and dosomethingElse **are both
evaluated** before test check, and I'm interested in evaluating just one. (I'm in a severe time constraint situation).

Is there a way to evaluate just one function in one line ?

Here, the main steps of the code. 'dependencies' are listed here, but they are well managed in the original program.

1. Create unique fun_id

   ```
   def gen_id():
       s = 10000
       while s:
           yield s
           s += 1

   fun_ticket = gen_id()
   ```
2. Fun descriptions (name, args, expression, id)

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict
   d= defaultdict(lambda :defaultdict())

   d["dosomething"]["args"] = set(["argA","argB"])
   d["dosomething"]["exp"] = "return argA + argB"
   d["dosomething"]["id"] = "f_%d"%(fun_ticket.next())

   d["dosomethingElse"]["args"] = set(["argX","argY","argZ"])
   d["dosomethingElse"]["exp"] = "return argX + argY+ argZ"
   d["dosomethingElse"]["id"] = "f_%d"%(fun_ticket.next())

   d["doChoice"]["args"] = set(["argE","argF"])
   d["doChoice"]["exp"] = "return [dosomethingElse, dosomething][argE > 0] + argF"
   d["doChoice"]["id"] = "f_%d"%(fun_ticket.next())
   ```
3. Prepare doChoice function to be evaluated.

   ```
   dependencies =  ('dosomething', 'dosomethingElse', 'doChoice')
   Allargs = set().union(*[d[x]["args"] for x in dependencies])


   funChoice = 'def %s(%s): %s'%(d['doChoice']['id'],",".join(Allargs),d['doChoice']["exp"])
   ```
4. Result: the funChoice string is :

   ```
   def f_10002(argX,argY,argZ,argA,argB,argE,argF): return [f_10001(argX,argY,argZ), f_10000(argA,argB)][argE > 0] + argF
   ```

Here is the problem: funChoice evaluation eval doSomething **AND** doSomethingElse. Is there a way to eval just one without using if else (and space management problems in string..) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
dosomething if test else dosomethingelse
```

Only one of `dosomething` and `dosomethingelse` will be evaluated depending on the outcome of `test`. Quoting the documentation:

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, *C* (*not x*); if *C* is true, *x* is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and its value is returned.

Adapting this to your code:

```
d["doChoice"]["exp"] = "return (dosomething if argE > 0 else dosomethingElse) + argF"
```

Comment: [fun1, [fun2,fun3] [test2] ][ test1 ]
<=??> fun3 if test2 else fun2 if test1 else fun1

Comment: You can chain or nest the conditional expressions. `(fun2 if test2 else fun3) if test1 else fun1`.

Comment: Lists creates confusion* even for python programers. I'm going to use your solution (if else). *(fun3 if test2 else fun2) if test1 else fun1.Thanks.

Comment: if dosomething and dosomethingElse have the same args, the list tip can be used `return [dosomethingElse, dosomething][ test ](args)`